# how to generate 5 minute intervals in MySQL using a generator table

Tags: mysql, intervals

I have these generator views:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_16
AS SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL
SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 12  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 15;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_256
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 4 ) | lo.n ) AS n
FROM generator_16 lo, generator_16 hi;
```

And then I have this simple code that generates

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') - INTERVAL n minute cardinal_interval 
FROM generator_256 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') - INTERVAL n minute >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 hour
```

If the current time is 2015-04-13 13:17:32

This generates

```
2015-04-13 13:17:00
2015-04-13 13:16:00
2015-04-13 13:15:00
2015-04-13 13:14:00
2015-04-13 13:13:00
2015-04-13 13:12:00
2015-04-13 13:11:00
2015-04-13 13:10:00
2015-04-13 13:09:00
...
2015-04-13 12:18:00
2015-04-13 12:17:00
```

So far so good. I simply want to know how to make it use the same generator table but give me rounded down 5 minute intervals so the result would be

If the current time is 2015-04-13 13:17:32:

```
2015-04-13 13:15:00
2015-04-13 13:10:00
2015-04-13 13:05:00
2015-04-13 13:00:00
2015-04-13 12:55:00
...
2015-04-13 12:15:00
```

I've been at this problem for hours. I came close to the desired result using some horrible mysql spaghetti code and just figured there must be a much cleaner way that I am just completely missing.

My understanding of how "INTERVAL n" works seems to be the problem here. Please help

Comment: Can you use a scripting language?

Comment: I can use stored procedures and other MySQL tricks but the solution needs to be fully from MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a way to do it. Please let me know if you can see an even cleaner way though. This is not that bad though I think but I wish I could do it without that extra cross join.

```
SELECT
    DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL @i:=@i-5 MINUTE) AS result_date
FROM
 generator_256
CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT @i:=5, @start_date:=FROM_UNIXTIME( TRUNCATE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) / 300,0) * 300)) AS init
WHERE 
    DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL @i MINUTE) > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 minute
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of doing this in sql at all